# Rails. How to get stat column from votes table where user_id = current user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, voting-system

I have petition site. I building now the voting system, but thats don't work glad.
To create only one vote per user I use this condition in view:

```
<% if @post.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).blank? %>
```

It's return true if user do not vote for current post.

But when i want to show user vote statement with this code:

```
<% if @post.votes(user_id: current_user.id) == 1 %>
        "u voted LIKE"
       <% else %>
        "u voted DISLIKE"
       <% end %>
```

it return me the error: **We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)**
I'm in development mode. Thanks.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your Rails setup, too. Normally you don't get a plain 500 error message like this in development mode, but the actual Ruby exception with a callstack and a whole lot of other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `where` and `count` in the statement.

try this,

```
 <% if @post.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).count.eql?(1) %>
    "u voted LIKE"
 <% else %>
    "u voted DISLIKE"
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the condition as

```
<% if @post.votes(user_id: current_user.id).count == 1 %>
        "u voted"
       <% else %>
        "u dont voted"
       <% end %>
```

You are counting the votes for that post of the user as 1 , if it is 1 then he has voted. else not voted.